# SQL: Is results order mapped to values in 'IN' expression?

Tags: sql

I have a list of record IDs for which I want to retrieve a single value from a table in SQL Server 2008.

My query is:

```
SELECT TestResult.FailureDetails FROM TestResult WHERE TestResult.ID IN (1,2,3,...)
```

The 'IN' expression contains hundreds of IDs. The ID column is the primary key of the table.

If my table is like:

```
ID    Value
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

Will I always get results ordered by order of appearance in the 'IN' expression? If not, I am considering doing:

```
SELECT TestResult.ID, TestResult.FailureDetails FROM TestResult WHERE TestResult.ID IN (1,2,3,...)
```

Comment: Do you always want in order of `ID` as per your example or do you need to support arbitrary orders?

Comment: In order of the ID would have been fine. Per the answer below, I am now selecting TestResult.ID as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not always get results in order based on the `IN`.

Be explicit, and add an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT FailureDetails 
FROM TestResult 
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,...) 
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if they were ordered by the `IN` clause. As you've got no `ORDER BY` you'll probably get the results in PK order, but I wouldn't depend on that either.

If order is important you should set it explicitly:

```
SELECT TestResult.ID, TestResult.FailureDetails FROM TestResult WHERE TestResult.ID IN (1,2,3,...)
ORDER BY TestResult.ID
```