# Oracle IN condition without sort

Tags: database, oracle

May I know is there any solution to get the result without ordering in Oracle? It is because when I execute the query as follows, it seems to automatically helps me to sort it by ID field.

```
SELECT ID FROM USER WHERE ID IN (5004, 5003, 5005, 5002, 5008);


Actual results          Expected results
---5002                 ---5004
---5003                 ---5003
---5004                 ---5005
---5005                 ---5002
---5008                 ---5008
```

Million thanks if you guys have solutions on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep order from 'IN' clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139931/keep-order-from-in-clause)

Comment: These questions should be merged :) Some answers here are different from there.

Answer (score 5):

This is one way I've seen in the past using `INSTR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID IN (5004, 5003, 5005, 5002, 5008)
ORDER BY INSTR ('5004,5003,5005,5002,5008', id)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c283/1)

I've also seen use of `CASE` like this:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE ID 
    WHEN 5004 THEN 1   
    WHEN 5003 THEN 2   
    WHEN 5005 THEN 3   
    WHEN 5002 THEN 4   
    WHEN 5008 THEN 5
  END
```

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT` statements return the rows of their result sets in an *unpredictable* order unless you give an `ORDER BY` clause.

Certain DBMS products give the illusion that their result sets are in a predictable order.  But if you rely on that you're bound to be disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the order as your in list, you can do something like this:

```
SQL> create type user_va as varray(1000) of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> with users as (select /*+ cardinality(a, 10) */ rownum r, a.column_value user_id
  2                   from table(user_va(11, 0, 19, 5)) a)
  3  select d.user_id, d.username
  4    from dba_users d
  5         inner join users u
  6                 on u.user_id = d.user_id
  7   order by u.r
  8  /

   USER_ID USERNAME
---------- ------------------------------
        11 OUTLN
         0 SYS
        19 DIP
         5 SYSTEM
```

i.e we put the elements into a varray and assign a rownum prior to merging the set. we can then order by that `r` to maintain the order of our in list. The `cardinality` hint just tells the optimizer how many rows are in the array (doesn't have to be dead on, just in the ballpark..as without this, it will assume 8k rows and may prefer a full scan over an index approach)

if you don't have privs to create a type and this is just some adhoc thing, there's a few public ones:

```
select owner, type_name, upper_bound max_elements, length max_size, elem_type_name
  from all_Coll_types
 where coll_type = 'VARYING ARRAY' 
and elem_type_name in ('INTEGER', 'NUMBER');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee of sort order without an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about *why the ordering occurs* then the answer is: Do you have an index or primary key defined on the column ID? If yes the database responds to your query with an index scan. That is: it looks up the IDs in the IN clause not in the table itself but in the index defined on your ID-column. Within the index the values are ordered.

To get more information about the execution of your query try Oracle's explain plan feature.

To get the values in a certain order you have to add an ORDER BY clause. One way of doing this would be

```
    select ID 
      from USER 
     where ID in (5004, 5003, 5005, 5002, 5008)
     order by
           case ID
             when 5004 then 1
             when 5003 then 2
             ...
           end;
```

A more general way would be to add an ORDERING column to your table:

```
    select ID 
      from USER 
     where ID in (5004, 5003, 5005, 5002, 5008)
     order by
           ORDERING;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I found here.

```
select ID 
    from USER 
where ID in (5004, 5003, 5005, 5002, 5008)
    order by decode(ID, 5002, 1, 5003, 2, 5004, 3, 5005, 4, 5008, 5);
```

order by decode(COLUMN NAME, VALUE, POSITION)

*Note: Only need to repeat the VALUE and POSITION

And yah, thanks for all the responds! I am really appreciate it.