# returning id in order from query

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
WHERE P_KEY IN (5,7,2,6);
```

When I enter the query, the P_KEY values return the rows in the order of 2,5,6,7.
How can I make it so it returns the rows in the order I entered it in the IN clause

This

```
P_KEY
5
7
2
6
```

NOT This

```
P_KEY
2
5
6
7
```

Comment: PLEASE, tag your question with what RDBMS you are using. If it is MySQL I have an exact answer for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep order from 'IN' clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139931/keep-order-from-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly order by the order of items in the `IN` clause.  You'll have to create a temporary table or in-line sub-query to add an order to the values:

```
SELECT Foo.* FROM FOO
INNER  JOIN
(
   SELECT 5 AS [Key], 1 AS [Order]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 7 AS [Key], 2 AS [Order]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 AS [Key], 3 AS [Order]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 6 AS [Key], 4 AS [Order]
) j
ON P_KEY = j.key
ORDER BY j.[Order]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and not so elegant solution is to use UNION

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE P_KEY =5
UNION
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE P_KEY =7
UNION
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE P_KEY =2
UNION
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE P_KEY =6
```

Comment: Is (5,7,2,6) something that a user selects, to be passed on as parameters to a stored procedure? If so, you can build the SQL by looping through those values. The proposed action above is more of a cheap and quick way to take care of your temporary problem, but I agree, in the long run you will need something more sophisticated :)