# JPA Query results in the input order

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

by default JPA entities are order by id.
Can we expect the result list in the order of input given to IN Clause?

example

```
List<Long> ids=  new ArrayList<Long>();
    ids.add(1004L);
    ids.add(1003L);
    ids.add(1001L);
    ids.add(1002L);


    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select p from Person p where p.id in (:pids)");
    query.setParameter("pids" , ids);
    List<Person> personsList= query.getResultList();
```

The personsList i get above is ordered by person ID, but i need the result list the order i provided(1004L,1003L,1001L,1002L)

Is that possible?

Note : Person not implemented compareTo()

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @PredragMaric oracle11g

Comment: I don't think JPA has any support for it, but there is a sort of ugly way to do this in Oracle using `order by case when ... then ... end`. Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139931/keep-order-from-in-clause)